# Exception in spring-solr-data showcase sample project

Tags: solr, spring-data, spring-data-solr

I get this exception when starting solr search example in spring data solr showcase (github [link](https://github.com/christophstrobl/spring-data-solr-showcase)). I am using solr: 6.1.0 and the default collection `gettingstarted` where in have put xml documents in `exampledocs` directory of solr.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [Assertion failed] - this argument is required; it must not be null
    org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
    org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:123)
    org.springframework.data.solr.core.convert.MappingSolrConverter$SolrPropertyValueProvider.readValue(MappingSolrConverter.java:321)
    org.springframework.data.solr.core.convert.MappingSolrConverter$SolrPropertyValueProvider.readCollection(MappingSolrConverter.java:439)
    org.springframework.data.solr.core.convert.MappingSolrConverter$SolrPropertyValueProvider.readValue(MappingSolrConverter.java:335)
    org.springframework.data.solr.core.convert.MappingSolrConverter$SolrPropertyValueProvider.readValue(MappingSolrConverter.java:312)
    org.springframework.data.solr.core.convert.MappingSolrConverter$SolrPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingSolrConverter.java:298)
    org.springframework.data.solr.core.convert.MappingSolrConverter.getValue(MappingSolrConverter.java:151)
    org.springframework.data.solr.core.convert.MappingSolrConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingSolrConverter.java:138)
    org.springframework.data.solr.core.convert.MappingSolrConverter$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingSolrConverter.java:130)
    org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:261)
    org.springframework.data.solr.core.convert.MappingSolrConverter.read(MappingSolrConverter.java:130)
    org.springframework.data.solr.core.convert.MappingSolrConverter.read(MappingSolrConverter.java:117)
    org.springframework.data.solr.core.convert.MappingSolrConverter.read(MappingSolrConverter.java:92)
    org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.convertSolrDocumentListToBeans(SolrTemplate.java:406)
    org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.convertQueryResponseToBeans(SolrTemplate.java:398)
    org.springframework.data.solr.core.SolrTemplate.queryForPage(SolrTemplate.java:277)
    org.springframework.data.solr.repository.support.SimpleSolrRepository.findAll(SimpleSolrRepository.java:112)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:358)
    org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:343)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    org.springframework.data.solr.showcase.product.$Proxy62.findAll(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.data.solr.showcase.product.ProductServiceImpl.findByName(ProductServiceImpl.java:46)
    org.springframework.data.solr.showcase.product.web.SearchController.search(SearchController.java:55)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the [branch](https://github.com/christophstrobl/spring-data-solr-showcase/tree/upgrade-to-spring-boot-1.4.0.M3) using a more recent version of Spring Boot and Solr and check the [Running Showcase (Solr 5)](https://github.com/christophstrobl/spring-data-solr-showcase/tree/upgrade-to-spring-boot-1.4.0.M3#running-showcase-solr-5) section in the readme. Should be the same procedure for Solr 6.